# Share a library across web applications

Tags: shared-service-provider, web-services

I have web application with lots of sitecollections, sites and libraries in it.

What is the best apporach to share one of this libraries wiht another web application in the same farm?

1. Just give the link to the library, and in the other web application a standard web part could be used to operate on that data (possible?)
2. Create a Shared Service and expose data from the library as a web service. Then consume that data in a webpart in the other web application?
3. Other???

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: Is this a different webapplication in the same farm or a different farm?

Comment: Yes, different web app, but same farm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sp2007 the OOB web services would be a way of doing this. In SharePoint 2010 you also have the option to use the Client Object Model and JQuery.

If data doesnt already exist in the other web applications, BCS would also be an option to share data across web apps.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion using Client Object Model and JQuery directly without wrapping in a service.

Comment: Hi again, the context of the question is found here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/7468/how-to-provide-a-generic-service-to-create-and-update-documents

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, but what about simply providing a rss feed of the library?